# note 5 signal refresh

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I am using a galaxy note 5 running android lollipop 5.1.1. At times, my phone will show "Emergency Calls Only", alerting me to the loss of signal. I can restart my phone and re-acquire signal successfully. My question is: is there a way to refresh network signal without restarting the phone?

Thanks

Comment: See if turning the radio on and off would help.

Comment: As Firelord suggested try turning _Flight mode_ ON and turn back OFF

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Airplane Mode, wait about 15 seconds, then turn off Airplane Mode.

Comment: OK - I tried: airplane mode would not turn off when I switched it off. I guess it was still looking for signal, and would come out of airplane mode once it was acquired. it's been a couple of minutes now and it will not get out of airplane mode.